# How to convert Bailey Borwein Plouffe algorithm from hex to decimal?

Tags: python, hex, string-formatting, pi

```
def S(j, n):
    k = 0
    s = 0
    left_sum = 0
    while (k <= n):
        denominator = 8k + j
        numerator = pow(16, n-k, denominator)
        left_sum = (left_sum + (numerator / denominator)) % 1.0
        k += 1
    right_sum = 0
    k = n + 1
    newt = 0
    while 1:
        numerator = pow(16, n-k)
        denominator = 8k + j
        check = numerator / denominator
        right_sum = newt + check
        if right_sum == check:
            break
        else:
            newt = right_sum
        k += 1

    result = left_sum + (right_sum % 1.0)
    return result


def pi(n):
    n -= 1
    x = (4*S(1, n) - 2*S(4, n) - S(5, n) - S(6, n)) % 1.0
```

I'm trying to find the nth digit of pi using the Bailey Borwein Plouffe algorithm. Because the algorithm uses hexadecimal, I need to convert it back into decimal. I found some code on Python fiddle that seems to do this properly:

```
return "%014x" % int(x * 16**14)
```

Could someone explain what this return statement is doing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This does not convert to decimal.  If anything, it converts a decimal value to a hexadecimal string.

This is [string formatting](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php), usually used for output.  The format specification is on the left, before the `%` separator; the value is on the right.

Value: `x * 16**14` is `x`, shifted left 14 hex digits.

Format: `%...x` specifies unsigned hexadecimal.
        `014` specifies a minimum of 14 columns, zero-padded.

The resulting string is returned to the calling program.

---

To convert to decimal, you'll need to

1. Fix your posted code.  This still has syntax errors.
2. Alter the base-specific code from hex to dec.  This starts with changing the power base from `16` to `10`.

If you get stuck, you can post your coding problem.  In that case, please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.